# Getting correct string length in Python for strings with ANSI color codes

Tags: python, escaping, ansi-colors

I've got some Python code that will automatically print a set of data in a nice column format, including putting in the appropriate ASCII escape sequences to color various pieces of the data for readability.

I eventually end up with each line being represented as a list, with each item being a column that is space-padded so that the same columns on each line are always the same length.  Unfortunately when I actually go to print this, not all the columns line up.  I suspect this is to do with the ASCII escape sequences - because the `len` function doesn't seem to recognize these:

```
>>> a = '\x1b[1m0.0\x1b[0m'
>>> len(a)
11
>>> print a
0.0
```

And so while each column is the same length according to `len`, they are not actually the same length when printed on the screen.

Is there any way (save for doing some hackery with regular expressions which I'd rather not do) to take the escaped string and find out what the printed length is so I can space pad appropriately?  Maybe some way to just "print" it back to string and examine the length of that?

Comment: These are actually "ANSI" color codes, not "ASCII", as would be shown on an ANSI color terminal, or on a PC using the ANSI.SYS driver.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pyparsing wiki includes this [helpful expression](http://pyparsing-public.wikispaces.com/Helpful+Expressions#toc7) for matching on ANSI escape sequences:

```
ESC = Literal('\x1b')
integer = Word(nums)
escapeSeq = Combine(ESC + '[' + Optional(delimitedList(integer,';')) + 
                oneOf(list(alphas)))
```

Here's how to make this into an escape-sequence-stripper:

```
from pyparsing import *

ESC = Literal('\x1b')
integer = Word(nums)
escapeSeq = Combine(ESC + '[' + Optional(delimitedList(integer,';')) + 
                oneOf(list(alphas)))

nonAnsiString = lambda s : Suppress(escapeSeq).transformString(s)

unColorString = nonAnsiString('\x1b[1m0.0\x1b[0m')
print unColorString, len(unColorString)
```

prints:

```
0.0 3
```

Comment: Technically the delimited list can have strings in it too, although it is unlikely you will ever meet such a sequence. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833873/python-regex-escape-characters/1834669#1834669

Comment: OH, don't I know it! In my youth, we made those VT100's dance, flashing their LED's, changing their scroll regions, outputting double-high-double-wide fonts, in bold reverse video - ah, what heady days those were...

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!  I was hoping there was just some blahlibrary.unescape() method somewhere I was overlooking, but this is the next best thing!

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand TWO things.

(1) It is your code, under your control. You want to add escape sequences to your data and then strip them out again so that you can calculate the length of your data?? It seems much simpler to calculate the padding **before** adding the escape sequences. What am I missing?

Let's presume that none of the escape sequences change the cursor position. If they do, the currently accepted answer won't work anyway.

Let's assume that you have the string data for each column (before adding escape sequences) in a list named `string_data` and the pre-determined column widths are in a list named `width`. Try something like this:

```
temp = []
for colx, text in enumerate(string_data):
    npad = width[colx] - len(text) # calculate padding size
    assert npad >= 0
    enhanced = fancy_text(text, colx, etc, whatever) # add escape sequences
    temp.append(enhanced + " " * npad)
sys.stdout.write("".join(temp))
```

---

**Update-1**

After OP's comment:

> The reason I want to strip them out and calculate the length after the
>   string contains the color codes is because all the data is built up
>   programmatically. I have a bunch of colorize methods and I'm building
>   up the data something like this: `str = "%s/%s/%s" % (GREEN(data1),
>   BLUE(data2), RED(data3))` It would be pretty difficult to color the
>   text after the fact.

If the data is built up of pieces each with its own formatting, you can still compute the displayed length and pad as appropriate. Here's a function which does that for one cell's contents:

```
BLACK, RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE = range(40, 48)
BOLD = 1

def render_and_pad(reqd_width, components, sep="/"):
    temp = []
    actual_width = 0
    for fmt_code, text in components:
        actual_width += len(text)
        strg = "\x1b[%dm%s\x1b[m" % (fmt_code, text)
        temp.append(strg)
    if temp:
        actual_width += len(temp) - 1
    npad = reqd_width - actual_width
    assert npad >= 0
    return sep.join(temp) + " " * npad

print repr(
    render_and_pad(20, zip([BOLD, GREEN, YELLOW], ["foo", "bar", "zot"]))
    )
```

If you think that the call is overburdened by punctuation, you could do something like:

```
BOLD = lambda s: (1, s)
BLACK = lambda s: (40, s)
# etc
def render_and_pad(reqd_width, sep, *components):
    # etc

x = render_and_pad(20, '/', BOLD(data1), GREEN(data2), YELLOW(data3))
```

**(2)** I don't understand why you don't want to use the supplied-with-Python regular expression kit? No "hackery" (for any possible meaning of "hackery" that I'm aware of) is involved:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "1\x1b[a2\x1b[42b3\x1b[98;99c4\x1b[77;66;55d5"
>>> expected = "12345"
>>> # regex = re.compile(r"\x1b\[[;\d]*[A-Za-z]")
... regex = re.compile(r"""
...     \x1b     # literal ESC
...     \[       # literal [
...     [;\d]*   # zero or more digits or semicolons
...     [A-Za-z] # a letter
...     """, re.VERBOSE)
>>> print regex.findall(test)
['\x1b[a', '\x1b[42b', '\x1b[98;99c', '\x1b[77;66;55d']
>>> actual = regex.sub("", test)
>>> print repr(actual)
'12345'
>>> assert actual == expected
>>>
```

**Update-2**

After OP's comment:

> I still prefer Paul's answer since it's more concise

More concise than what? Isn't the following regex solution concise enough for you?

```
# === setup ===
import re
strip_ANSI_escape_sequences_sub = re.compile(r"""
    \x1b     # literal ESC
    \[       # literal [
    [;\d]*   # zero or more digits or semicolons
    [A-Za-z] # a letter
    """, re.VERBOSE).sub
def strip_ANSI_escape_sequences(s):
    return strip_ANSI_escape_sequences_sub("", s)

# === usage ===
raw_data = strip_ANSI_escape_sequences(formatted_data)
```

[Above code corrected after @Nick Perkins pointed out that it didn't work]

Comment: Thanks for the answer John.  The reason I want to strip them out and calculate the length *after* the string contains the color codes is because all the data is built up programmatically.  I have a bunch of colorize methods and I'm building up the data something like this:

str = "%s/%s/%s" % (GREEN(data1), BLUE(data2), RED(data3))

It would be pretty difficult to color the text after the fact.  As for hackery, maybe what I should have said was, "I imagine this is a solved problem and I just can't find the right library".  Guess not, but I still prefer Paul's answer since it's more concise.

Comment: OK, I'll bite on this.  I see what you're getting at with calculating the length as you go.  The solution you propose doesn't quite work, just because knowing the desired column length ahead of time requires that you know the length of the largest string to be stored in a cell of that column.  Nonetheless, I don't think it'd be too hard to write something that got around this and didn't require stripping the color sequences out after the fact.

Comment: As for the regex comment, I don't have any problem using Python's built in support.  I just generally tend to shy away from doing regex parsing because it's easy to mess it up and forget some edge case.  See the unending list of questions here on SO from people trying to use regexes with HTML for proof of that.  Or, just look at the comment on Paul's post, which points out that what he provided doesn't actually account for non-color control codes.   That said, when only worried about colors, it's pretty straightforward as you've shown.

Comment: "Forgetting" the implementation of an edge case is independent of the implementation tool (pyParsing, regex, assembly language). Regexes are incapable of parsing HTML properly; the unending list of questions from people who don't know that proves nothing. Actually, the comment on Paul's post referred to sequences with a string constant parameter instead of an integer constant, and mentioned that they are rare. Colour-related sequences are a small subset of the set graphic rendition command, and that's just one of many commands. You haven't addressed "more concise".

Comment: the code to strip sequences does not work:  '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object is not callable -- don't you need to call some "replace" function or something?

Comment: This works: return re.sub(strip_ANSI_escape_sequences_regex,"",s)

Comment: @Nick Perkins: Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected it to do the compile and attribute lookup in the setup.

Answer (score 1):

Looking in [ANSI_escape_code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), the sequence in your example is
**Select Graphic Rendition** (probably **bold**).

Try to control column positioning with the **CUrsor Position** ( `CSI n ; m H`) sequence.
This way, width of preceding text does not affect current column position and there is no need to worry about string widths.

A better option, if you target Unix, is using the [curses module window-objects](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#window-objects).
For example, a string can be positioned on the screen with:

> `window.addnstr([y, x], str, n[, attr])`
>
> Paint at most n characters of the string str at (y, x) with attributes attr, overwriting anything previously on the display.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just adding color to some cells, you can add 9 to the expected cell width (5 hidden characters to turn on the color, 4 to turn it off), e.g.

```
import colorama # handle ANSI codes on Windows
colorama.init()

RED   = '\033[91m' # 5 chars
GREEN = '\033[92m' # 5 chars
RESET = '\033[0m'  # 4 chars

def red(s):
    "color a string red"
    return RED + s + RESET
def green(s):
    "color a string green"
    return GREEN + s + RESET
def redgreen(v, fmt, sign=1):
    "color a value v red or green, depending on sign of value"
    s = fmt.format(v)
    return red(s) if (v*sign)<0 else green(s)

header_format = "{:9} {:5}  {:>8}  {:10}  {:10}  {:9}  {:>8}"
row_format =    "{:9} {:5}  {:8.2f}  {:>19}  {:>19}  {:>18}  {:>17}"
print(header_format.format("Type","Trial","Epsilon","Avg Reward","Violations", "Accidents","Status"))

# some dummy data
testing = True
ntrials = 3
nsteps = 1
reward = 0.95
actions = [0,1,0,0,1]
d = {'success': True}
epsilon = 0.1

for trial in range(ntrials):
    trial_type = "Testing " if testing else "Training"
    avg_reward = redgreen(float(reward)/nsteps, "{:.2f}")
    violations = redgreen(actions[1] + actions[2], "{:d}", -1)
    accidents = redgreen(actions[3] + actions[4], "{:d}", -1)
    status = green("On time") if d['success'] else red("Late")
    print(row_format.format(trial_type, trial, epsilon, avg_reward, violations, accidents, status))
```

Giving

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you describe some more about what you're doing here? I mean you're mixing format with colors, so its a bit confusing to look at. And how does the output look? (Hard to know how it's done without seeing that.

Comment: @not2qubit sure, I added some comments and a screenshot - hopefully that clarifies it a bit