# Python’s `str.format()`, fill characters, and ANSI colors

Tags: python, string, terminal, ansi-colors

In Python 2, I’m using `str.format()` to align a bunch of columns of text I’m printing to a terminal.  Basically, it’s a table, but I’m not printing any borders or anything—it’s simply rows of text, aligned into columns.

- With no color-fiddling, everything prints as expected.
- If I wrap an entire row (i.e., one `print` statement) with ANSI color codes, everything prints as expected.
- **However:** If I try to make each column a different color within a row, the alignment is thrown off.  Technically, the *alignment* is preserved; it’s *the fill characters* (spaces) that aren’t printing as desired; in fact, the fill characters seem to be completely removed.

I’ve verified the same issue with both [`colorama`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) and [`xtermcolor`](https://github.com/broadinstitute/xtermcolor/).  The results were the same.  Therefore, I’m certain the issue has to do with `str.format()` not playing well with ANSI escape sequences in the middle of a string.

But I don’t know what to do about it! :(  I would really like to know if there’s any kind of workaround for this problem.

Color and alignment are powerful tools for improving readability, and readability is an important part of software usability.  It would mean a lot to me if this could be accomplished without manually aligning each column of text.

Little help? ☺

Comment: You'll need to show us (some of) your code if you want anything more specific than just "Python .format() doesn't treat ANSI escape characters any different".

Comment: I understand it’s tricker to help without the code itself.  Sorry about that.  I was hoping for an answer like @MartijnPieters posted below, though.  If I don’t have any luck with that, I’ll go ahead and post the code.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186919/getting-correct-string-length-in-python-for-strings-with-ansi-color-codes/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a very late answer, left as bread crumbs for anyone who finds this page while struggling to format text with built-in ANSI color codes.

[byoungb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140756/python-s-str-format-fill-characters-and-ansi-colors#comment73552881_14140783) about making padding decisions on the length of pre-colorized text is exactly right. But if you already have colored text, here's a work-around:

See my [ansiwrap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansiwrap) module on PyPI. Its primary purpose is providing `textwrap` for ANSI-colored text, but it also exports `ansilen()` which tells you "how long would this string be if it *didn't* contain ANSI control codes?" It's quite useful in making formatting, column-width, and wrapping decisions on pre-colored text. Add `width - ansilen(s)` spaces to the end or beginning of `s` to left (or respectively, right) justify `s` in a column of your desired `width`. E.g.:

```
def ansi_ljust(s, width):
    needed = width - ansilen(s)
    if needed > 0:
        return s + ' ' * needed
    else:
        return s
```

Also, if you need to split, truncate, or combine colored text at some point, you will find that ANSI's stateful nature makes that a chore. You may find `ansi_terminate_lines()` helpful; it "patch up" a list of sub-strings so that each has independent, self-standing ANSI codes with equivalent effect as the original string.

The latest versions of [ansicolors](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansicolors) also contain an equivalent implementation of `ansilen()`.

Comment: Thank you for that ansiwrap module! For anyone struggling to use terminal coloring with prettytable like I was, edit prettytable.py and replace `import textwrap` with `import ansiwrap as textwrap`.

Comment: Update five years later: ansiwrap hasn't been maintained for a while and [has been spitting out deprecation notices for a couple years](https://github.com/jonathaneunice/ansiwrap/issues/17). This has been a problem for some package managers of an application I maintain that depends on it.

Answer (score 7):

Python doesn't distinguish between 'normal' characters and ANSI colour codes, which are also characters that the terminal interprets.

In other words, printing `'\x1b[92m'` to a terminal may change the terminal text colour, Python doesn't see that as anything but a set of 5 characters. If you use `print repr(line)` instead, python will print the string literal form instead, including using escape codes for non-ASCII printable characters (so the ESC ASCII code, 27, is displayed as `\x1b`) to see how many have been added.

You'll need to adjust your column alignments manually to allow for those extra characters.

Without your actual code, that's hard for us to help you with though.

Comment: Ahhh, interesting!  I’ll give it a shot and see what I can do.  If I don’t have any luck, I’ll post the code.  (I want to avoid it if possible, though, cause it’s messy, and I’m mildly embarassed.  Shh!)

Comment: I found it easier to do the padding to the string you passed to have colorized. This works if you have no background color or don't care if the padding has the background color applied to it.
`stdout.write('{:s}\t [{:s}]\n'.format(x, colorize('{:^10}'.format(y), 'red'))`

Answer (score 1):

Also late to the party. Had this same issue dealing with color and alignment. Here is a function I wrote which adds padding to a string that has characters that are 'invisible' by default, such as escape sequences.

```
def ljustcolor(text: str, padding: int, char=" ") -> str:
    import re
    pattern = r'(?:\x1B[@-_]|[\x80-\x9F])[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]'

    matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
    offset = sum(len(match) for match in matches)
    return text.ljust(padding + offset,char[0])
```

The pattern matches all ansi escape sequences, including color codes. We then get the total length of all matches which will serve as our offset when we add it to the padding value in ljust.