# Python counting zero-length control characters in string formatting width field?

Tags: python, terminal, printf

In Python 3.4.3, I was trying to width-align some fields using the string.format() operator, and it appears to count zero-length control characters against the width total. Sample code:

```
ANSI_RED = "\033[31m"
ANSI_DEFAULT="\033[39m\033[49m"

string1 = "12"
string2 = ANSI_RED+"12"+ANSI_DEFAULT

print("foo{:4s}bar".format(string1))
print("foo{:4s}bar".format(string2))
```

This will output:

```
foo12  bar
foo12bar
```

(with the second output having '12' in red, but I can't reproduce that in SO)

In the second case, I've lost my field width, I assume because Python saw that the total number of chars in the string was larger than the width, despite most of those chars resulting in zero-length on an ANSI-conforming terminal.

What's a clean way of having ANSI colors and working field widths?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186919/getting-correct-string-length-in-python-for-strings-with-ansi-color-codes may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's a clean way of having ANSI colors and working field widths?

Unfortunately, you will have to strip the escape sequences to get a displayed field width.

The `len()` function returns the number of bytes in a Python 2 str type and the number of code points in a Python 3 str type.  That length has never been guaranteed to match the display width (which is a more challenging problem):

```
>>> s = 'abc\bde'
>>> print s
abcde
>>> len(s)
6
```

In general, you can't know the display width for certain unless you know something about how the display will interpret the codes (i.e. the width is different depending on whether the device supports ANSI escape sequences).

Comment: Thanks! i was afraid it would come to that, but the voice of authority has spoken :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will qualify as "clean" but something in the vain of the following is workable:

```
print("foo{0}{1:4s}{2}bar".format(ANSI_RED, string1, ANSI_DEFAULT))
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that! Unfortunately that generated string is itself used as input for more formatting, so I'd either need to keep track of the display length as I build it up or, as Raymond suggested, just strip the escapes to calculate.

Comment: This is what i tend to do in shell scripts then have functions like `success($msg)` that prints green and `warn($msg)` that prints yellow. It adds some semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Getting terminal control codes right is really difficult (as seen below, not all of them have a well-defined width), so your best bet is probably to use explicit column movement.

```
# string2 defined as above
def col(n): return "\033[{:d}G".format(n)
print("foo{:s}{:s}bar".format(string2,col(8)))
```

Output:

```
foo12  bar
```

Comment: Yikes! My first reflex is that if I'm going to go there, may as well pull out a full ncurses library

Comment: @john: i was going to suggest that, too:-) But column alignment is column alignment, no? It would be relatively easy to write cols(widths, strings).