# Regular expression for separating ANSI escape characters from text

Tags: python, regex

I use colorama to add ANSI codes to text, I need to split the ANSI color codes from the text so the text can be printed in column formats. The following expression separates a single color code from the text, but not a double code.

```
# adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186919
split_ANSI_escape_sequences = re.compile(r"""
    (?P<col>
    \x1b     # literal ESC
    \[       # literal [
    [;\d]*   # zero or more digits or semicolons
    [A-Za-z] # a letter
    )*
    (?P<text>.*)
    """, re.VERBOSE).fullmatch

def split_ANSI(s):
    return split_ANSI_escape_sequences(s).groupdict()
```

This is the result:

```
>>> split_ANSI('\x1b[31m\x1b[1mtext')
{'col': '\x1b[1m', 'text': 'text'}
```

It splits correctly, but loses the formatting information. I'm expecting

```
{'col': '\x1b[31m\x1b[1m', 'text': 'text'}
```

as the result.

How can I get all the potential escape sequences in the first group?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: {'col': '\x1b[31m\x1b[1m', 'text': 'text'}

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that.

Comment: Should that lone `*` not be inside the first named group? Without the named group expression, it seems to repeat just that last `A-Za-z`.

Comment: @RadLexus, I wasn't sure what you were saying, but I did find the answer. The lone * was overwriting the named group, so it needs another level of grouping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer at [Python RegEx multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963691) by asking the question different ways.

The first named group gets overwritten by each match. This version works:

```
split_ANSI_escape_sequences = re.compile(r"""
    (?P<col>(\x1b     # literal ESC
    \[       # literal [
    [;\d]*   # zero or more digits or semicolons
    [A-Za-z] # a letter
    )*)
    (?P<name>.*)
    """, re.VERBOSE).match

def split_ANSI(s):
    return split_ANSI_escape_sequences(s).groupdict()
```