# How to check for ANSI character in Python

Tags: python, ansi

I'm trying to validate a set of strings to **report out the usage of illegal ANSI characters**. I've read that **extended ASCII** is **NOT** exactly similar to **ANSI**. I've been trying to search for a way to check if a character is an ANSI character, but so far I found none. Does anyone know how to do this in Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format suggests "ansi" is not enough to specify an encoding. Which specific ANSI encoding do you wish to validate?

Comment: The other question is what exactly you mean by illegal characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with ord(c) function:

```
def detect_non_printable(s):
    for c in s: 
        n = ord(c)
        if n < 32 or n > 126: 
           return "NON-PRINTABLE DETECTED" 
    return "PRINTABLE CHARS ONLY"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you with detecting any ANSI character in a text :

```
split_ANSI_escape_sequences = re.compile(r"""
    (?P<col>(\x1b     # literal ESC
    \[       # literal [
    [;\d]*   # zero or more digits or semicolons
    [A-Za-z] # a letter
    )*)
    (?P<name>.*)
    """, re.VERBOSE).match

def split_ANSI(s):
    return split_ANSI_escape_sequences(s).groupdict()
```

Found this code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708623/regular-expression-for-separating-ansi-escape-characters-from-text) question.