# How count the right length of python color string?

Tags: python

I want count the yellow "tip" string for showing in terminal, but i can't find right method.

```
tip: str = "\033[0;33mtip\033[0m"
length: int = len(tip)
print("len = " + str(length))
```

Output:

```
len = 14
```

But it real length is 3! What can i do???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting correct string length in Python for strings with ANSI color codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186919/getting-correct-string-length-in-python-for-strings-with-ansi-color-codes)

Comment: Just for the sake of conversation, you have the string's length, which is 14, and you have "how much space will this take on screen?"  You can't really call that the length.

Comment: It need `pyparsing` @Ming

Comment: Have any method? @TimRoberts