# Unable to convert a string to and integer with python in fabric

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

This is driving me nuts.
I am using fabric to do some video processing tasks on a remote server via SSH.

I make a call to ffprobe on the remote machine to get the info back on the video that I will have sent over to that server before we enter this function.  I am trying to parse out the bit about Duration: from the output of ffprobe so I can get the length of the video in seconds.  This is the troublesome part of the function where I cannot seem to convert a string to an integer.

```
with cd("~/videos"):
   command = "ffprobe  "
   command += videoNameOnly
   output = run(command)
   durationIndex = output.find("Duration:")
   durationIndex = durationIndex + 10
   duration = output[durationIndex:]
   durationFrags = duration.split(":")
   print "====================================="
   print durationFrags[0].strip()
   print durationFrags[1].strip()
   print durationFrags[2].strip()
   hours = int(durationFrags[0].strip())
```

The output from this is as follows

```
00
00
52.90, start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 712, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 298, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 197, in _execute
    return task.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 112, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amyface/fabfile.py", line 26, in main
    encode();
  File "/home/amyface/fabfile.py", line 34, in encode
    runJobs(jobs,cursor)
  File "/home/amyface/fabfile.py", line 60, in runJobs
    getMiddleFrame(sourceVideo,videoNameOnly,cursor)
  File "/home/amyface/fabfile.py", line 96, in getMiddleFrame
    hours = int(durationFrags[0].strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x1b[0m\x1b[0;39m\x1b[0m\x1b[0;39m\x1b[0m\x1b[0;39m00'
Disconnecting from [I have removed the server name from here]
```

How come it wont let me convert "00" into an integer?
Also what is the strange value in the error after "with base 10: "?

Comment: is the problem only with '00' ?. can you convert the '52.90' value (to float obviously) ? your integers are base 10 by default

Comment: Yeah It lets me parse the last number.  Another interesting thing ... 
print str(durationFrags[0]) == "00" outputs False

Comment: Only the first 00 won't parse. I can't int() the second 00 or the 52.90

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about fabric, but according to the `ValueError`, `durationFrags[0].strip()` is `'\x1b[0m\x1b[0;39m\x1b[0m\x1b[0;39m\x1b[0m\x1b[0;39m00'`, not `'00'`. Does this produce output that's designed to go to a terminal? Those look like ANSI escape codes to me.

Answer (score 1):

The key is this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:  '\x1b[0m\x1b[0;39m\x1b[0m\x1b[0;39m\x1b[0m\x1b[0;39m00'
```

As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833873/python-regex-escape-characters) these are ANSI terminal codes. In the string, `\x1b` are `ESC` characters

You could use a regex as shown in the answers of the above link to remove unwanted codes and extract the last '00'

Answer (score 0):

The command executed (`ffprobe`) is writing [terminal color codes](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting).

Try telling this program to not use them by setting the `AV_LOG_FORCE_NOCOLOR` environment variable